# Keyboard backlight not working in Windows 10

Tags: keyboard, bootcamp

I always have had this problem and it used to work with resetting SMC, but not anymore. I've been Googling this for a long time and yet to find a way that would work for me.

When I press the corresponding keys, I get the backlight icon we see in macOS but with a disable icon underneath it. Backlight is working fine in macOS.

Things I've tried on top of my head from various people hinting it:

1. Killing its process and starting it with Admin privileges.
2. Since I've just installed Windows and Bootcamp, it doesn't need updating, is at 6.0.
3. I'm using United Sates (Apple Keyboard).
4. Haven't installed Power Plan Assistant.
5. In Windows Mobility Center there is no Keyboard enry.
6. No Unknown Device in Device Manager.
7. I have Light Sensor in Device Manager.
8. Covering light sensor does not change anything.

I'm using Mid-2012 MBP (Non-removable battery) using Windows 10 (Build 1089 Redstone 5).